# run a python file immidiately after alt+tab

Tags: wmctrl

I wrote a python file, which based on wmctrl output of the current window, changes the panel color. I want to bind this file to the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> . I tried using system shortcuts but It disables the normal function of <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. 
explaining this issue is kinda hard.
consider sometimes you hold the <kbd>Alt</kbd>key , and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> key multiple times to switch to the desired window.
I want right after releasing the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key , this python file to be run.
I simply want to know, what is the complete command for <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> behavior (obviously I want a wmctrl syntax-based), then do something like :

`sh -c "command 1; command 2"`

which command 1 : is the command for <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>
and command 2 : is something like : python3 file.py

please help me

Answer (score 1):

Look into `dbus-monitor` (https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-monitor.1.html). It is probably already installed on your system.

You could run `dbus-monitor "interface=org.gnome.Shell.Introspect"` as a service on your system. It will fire every time you press Alt-Tab:

```
signal time=1589208011.321827 sender=:1.54 -> destination=(null destination) serial=17043 path=/org/gnome/Shell/Introspect; interface=org.gnome.Shell.Introspect; member=RunningApplicationsChanged
method call time=1589208011.322378 sender=:1.44 -> destination=:1.54 serial=489 path=/org/gnome/Shell/Introspect; interface=org.gnome.Shell.Introspect; member=GetRunningApplications
```

Comment: this is just for monitoring . I need to add a new functionality to alt+tab

Comment: Well, you could write a script that starts listening to dbus, and, when this specific signal occurs, does your `wmctrl` magic.

Comment: the output differs depending on what is the previous and next window . this cannot be used as a global solution

Comment: It's enough to know that it has fired, isn't it?